# Как парсить секцию faces obj файла?

Tags: java, opengl, obj

Задача создать парсер obj файла. Скачал готовый файл obj:

```
# Blender v2.75 (sub 0) OBJ File: 'oldWall.blend'
# www.blender.org
mtllib oldWall.mtl
o baseTwo_Cube.002
v -4.539207 0.177720 0.778252
v -4.539207 0.177720 -0.381311
...
v -3.868980 3.860143 0.108025
v -3.868980 3.860143 0.288916
vt 0.139063 0.558805
vt 0.036272 0.726177
...
vt 0.421907 0.727517
vt 0.243928 0.773530
vn -0.691700 0.722100 0.000000
...
vn -0.871500 0.490400 -0.000000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 10/3/1 9/4/1
f 8/5/2 7/6/2 19/7/2 20/8/2
...
```

1. Почему в face 4 параметра, как его парсить?
2. Как рисовать треугольники, с помощью GL_TRIANGLES или GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP?

Comment: Пожалуйста, формулируйте по 1 вопросу в вопросе. Не бойтесь задавать несколько вопросов отдельно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**По первому вопросу:**

4 тройки чисел действительно означают, что примитив - четырехугольник. Не вчитывался в Ваш файл, но если встречаются неплоские четырехугольники, то могут возникнуть проблемы, потому что его можно триангулировать двумя способами: "1-2-3 и 1-3-4" либо "1-2-4 и 2-3-4". При этом неправильно выпирающее диагональное ребро может испортить внешний вид объекта.

Если Вас это не беспокоит, то просто нужно разбить процесс парсинга файла на 2 этапа: сначала просто прочитать все вершины и примитивы, затем триангулировать четырехугольники. Триангулирование коснется только массива индексов - их нужно будет перетасовать в нужном порядке.

**По второму вопросу:**

Ответ на него следует из первого: Вы должны сами решить, какой способ рендеринга использовать - list либо strip, и в зависимости от этого подготовить массив индексов соответствующим образом. Если Вы имели в виду производительность, то, насколько я знаю, strips эффективнее.

**UPD:** забыл сказать, я использую 3dsmax для создания obj-файлов, - там можно выбрать в качестве примитивов и четырехугольники, и треугольники. Судя по первым строкам, у Вас Blender - может, и там есть такая опция?

Comment: Да, я разобрался, а файл я просто скачал. Спасибо!

Comment: В Blendere опция при выгрузке Triangulate Faces есть.

Answer (score 1):

4 индекса означают что примитив - четырёхугольник.

Comment: А как нарисовать четырехугольник? я использую Opengl es 2.0 на Android

Comment: @CJ1, как два треугольника.